# Is there a standard library function that you can use to prevent escape characters from being recognized as such?

Tags: c++, escaping

Basically I'm using the Stanford C++ Library's GWindow class to display the contents of a file, but many of the lines of the file end in a backslash "\". Is there a way to make the computer "ignore" the backslash? I'm trying to use the setLabel function and that backslash is messing everything up.

An example:

I have a vector, frame, which is full of strings of various symbols. Here is an example string:

```
"               /| || |\                /|\ / |\"
```

I want to use the Stanford C++ Library's GWindow class (http://stanford.edu/~stepp/cppdoc/GWindow-class.html) to display the various lines of text. To do this, I have created a vector screens of 13 labels, which will fill the window with text, and can be changed using the setLabel() function (the documentation can be found in the link above)

So when I loop through my strings to reset the labels, I will basically do

```
for (int i = 0; i < screens.size(); i++)
{
     screens[i]->setLabel(frames[i]);
}
```

But when I do so the program gets stuck at the first line that ends in a backslash.

How can I avoid this problem?

Edit: I see this is marked as duplicate but none of the suggestions worked. Is there a way to convert a string to a raw string literal?

Comment: Could you show some code, sample input and sample output, to make the question more clear?

Comment: Sure, I'll add some more details.

Comment: @NickyC added more info!

Comment: Looks to me that you would need to reduplicate all backslashes to make it work...

Comment: What do you mean by, "gets stuck"?  Is there an error message?

Comment: @PkP is there a native way to do that, other than just looping through, checking if the last character is a backslash, and then adding an additional one if it is?

Comment: @MarkTolonenIt just stops... Nothing happens and the window freezes. Sorry for the vague language, I'm about to run a debugger

Comment: Backslashes are only of importance in C++ when preprocessing the program code, as a way of making it possible to include otherwise difficult (or impossible) to type characters. Your characters are coming from a file, so the preprocessor is irrelevant. I can't immediately see anything in cslib that indicates it does something special with backslashes. Debugging should give you more to go on, but I'd look into how you're reading the file.

Comment: @notmyfriend Interesting, although setLabel is from a third party library, would that make a difference?

Comment: @notmyfriend Also I can have it print everything to the console just fine, but when I want to print it to the window (using setLabel) it craps out on me.

Comment: I think you have a problem with how you're setting up/managing your labels and/or screens, but without seeing the code it's only speculation. Have you seen with a debugger or debugging print statements how many iterations into your loop you actually get before it dies?

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that you would need to duplicate all the backslashes to make it work. The final backslash and quotation mark \" means that the quotation mark becomes included in your string, so in effect you have an unterminated string, which the compiler probably doesn't like at all.

Try:

```
"               /| || |\\                /|\\ / |\\"
```

Comment: Right, but how would I do that? I can't go through and edit the input file, it's an assignment for class and I can't touch those. Do I have to loop through each line, check the terminating character, and if it is a \ add an additional one? Would something like `if (frame[i][frame[i].size()-1] == '\'){frame[i] += "\""}` work?

Comment: Hmm, is that input file a .C, .CC or .CPP file?

Comment: .ani, actually, but I have no troubles getting all the text into a vector of each line so I don't think I need to do anything to the file itself

Comment: Ok, I thought that it was a C++ input file, so my answer actually doesn't apply - I thought that the C++ compiler was reading that file and choking on the backslashes.

Comment: Gotcha, well thanks anyway for trying. I might try it anyway and see if it helps.